# nativescript include new element to view after app is already built

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

I need download some view element from the backend and show it on my application. But I really don't know if it's possible to do it on nativescript. If it's possible to modify view after the app is build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You could fetch the .xml, .js, or .css file from a remote location and then dynamically change the markup of a view.